# Why is Angular putting the ng-scope class on an element that doesn't have a scope attached

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a jQuery plugin that does template transformation, and an Angular directive that integrates with the plugin by calling $compile after the plugin runs on the produced DOM node:

```
//in the link function of tiFormRender directive
element.empty();
compileForm(newForm, tiForms.frameworks(), element);
$compile(element.children())(scope);
```

This correctly processes directives in the subtree produced by the plugin, but for some reason it adds the class `ng-scope` to the compiled template:

```
<div ti-form-render="testForm">
    <md-content class="layout-padding ng-scope layout-row">
        <-- more DOM -->    
    </md-content>
</div>
```

The `ti-form-render` element (the original directive which does not create a scope) and the `md-content` element have the same scope as I would expect (verified with `element.scope()`) so why did Angular attach the `ng-scope` class to an element that doesn't actually have a scope?

Comment: you just used `$compile` with scope as argument. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I thought it only added the classes where scopes were created and attached, not just attached.

Comment: no, it gets added to any bindings as far as I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-scope` is added to any element where a scope is attached (one scope can be attached in multiple places), and since the $compile process attaches a scope to a template, it adds the class to the processed template. It just looks a bit weird here since the scope it's attaching is the same one as the parent element, due to my hacky solution.